# heapsort in Ada

Tags: arrays, ada, heapsort

I'm a beginner in Ada, and I have an assignment which is a line-by-line conversion of a heap sort program in C++ to Ada.

I wrote the ada code but I seem to have problems with the pointer or the array and the loop counter.

This is what I got :

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
procedure prob1 is
n : integer;
type arr1 is array (1..n) of integer ;
type Int_Acc is access all arr1 ; -- declaration of a pointer
procedure max_heapify (Int_Acc : access arr1 ; n : integer; i : integer)  is
  j : integer;
  temp : integer;
begin
  temp := Int_Acc(i);
  j := 2*i;

  while j <= n loop
     if j < n and Int_Acc(j+1) > Int_Acc(j) then
        j := j+1;
     elsif temp > Int_Acc(j) then
     exit when temp > Int_Acc(j);
     elsif temp <= Int_Acc(j) then
        Int_Acc(j/2) := Int_Acc(j);
         j := 2*j;
     end if;
   Int_Acc(j/2) := temp;
     end loop;
end max_heapify;
procedure heapsort (Int_Acc : access arr1 ; n : integer) is
   i : integer;
  temp : integer;
  begin
  while i>=2 loop
    temp := Int_Acc (i);
  Int_Acc(i) := Int_Acc (1);
     Int_Acc (1) := temp;
     i := i -1;
  max_heapify (arr1,1,i);
  end loop;
end heapsort;
procedure build_maxheap (Int_Acc : access arr1 ; n : integer) is
  begin
  while i >= 1 loop
      i := i -1;
     max_heapify (Int_Acc,n,i);
 end loop;
 end build_maxheap;
 m:integer ;
 i: integer;
 x:integer;
 begin
 put_line ("enetr the number of elemets of the array : ");
 Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(n);
  for k in arr1'Range loop
    put_line ("enter element" & integer'Image(k));
   Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(arr1(i));
end loop;
build_maxheap (arr1,m);
heapsort(arr1 , m);
put_line("sorted output is : ");
  for j in arr1'Range loop
    put_line(Integer'Image (arr1(i)));
 end loop;
 end prob1;
```

[Here are the errors I get](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=AF730F27BE981FC9!1637&authkey=!ADaZeS_zAAd47Js&v=3&ithint=photo,.png)

I really failed to figure it out, but I really think the problem is in the pointer of the array.
I hope that you provide me with any help possible, this assignment is due soon and I need to submit it running.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get what you mean. Are you indicating it's copied? or you just don't like how it looks?

I prefer a useful clear advice on this please :)

Comment: that means that you might get the answer you need if you look at these questions.

Comment: @BrianDrummond The first link you posted was for a question where he had some errors at runtime.  This OP hasn't gotten his code to compile yet.  I don't see how this is a duplicate at all, nor do I see how he could get his questions answered by looking there.

Comment: `arr1` is a type name, and you have used it in several places where the program needs a variable, or some other expression whose *type* is `arr1`.  It's like writing `int` in C++ code where you need a variable of type `int`.

Comment: @ajb thank you !! that's what was causing the issue, plus I used in out reference and didn't change the loop. It's running correctly now, Thank you all very much.

Comment: OK Thanks @ajb I'll delete my comments.